# Route physical location to rewrited url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I understand how routing works in asp.net web from.

I want to prevent users to access urls like 'Default.aspx'. So when a user tried access url like 'Default.aspx' it redirected to 'Default'.

For example i tried this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "Default.aspx", "~/Default");
```

but it does not work! Is there another way?

Please excuse me for poor and bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Webforms or MVC? It's not clear from your question and tagging....

Where have you added this code in your app? It needs to be in application_start() in global.ascx for a WebForms app.

Alternatively, You can try re-writing the url in the web.config (in system.webServer):

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>     
      <rule name="MyRuleName" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^default$" ignoreCase="true" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="/default.aspx" />
      </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Yes add this to application_start().
web.config approach does not help me. because it does same as i did in application_start.